# Making PORT 443 free

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, proxy, port

I have a proxy and need to set it to listen on port 443. It is running on my Ubuntu and I am wondering if I can make the port 443 free in order to give it to my proxy. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can if there is no other service already listening on port 443 and your proxy process has sufficient privileges to bind to port 443. You can use `lsof` or `netstat`, or `sockstat` to determine if anything is listening on `port 443`. You can also use `telnet <hostname> 443`  and if the connection succeds, it means there is a process already listening on `port 443`.

Comment: Thanks. I know and there is already a service listening on this port. TCP (HTTPS). My question is, am I able to unblock this port and give it to my proxy? In fact, I want my proxy to receive all the https requests sent by my browser. Is that possible?